# Android - Spinner arrow does not show when background is imageview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-spinner, android-xml

I have a simple layout where I'm using Imageview as background because I want to use the property "scaleType". I Placed the Imageview first in my relative layout and placed the Spinner right after.

The spinner arrow does not show. If I'm removing the the Imageview or placing my image as a background image (in the relative layout) it will show.

Here is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/White">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="7dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:src="@drawable/background" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerGameType"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add:

```
android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
```

to your Spinner in layout

```
 <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerGameType"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

**Option 2:**

use a custom drawable with your custom arrow down image for the spinner

in drawable/custom_spinner.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

            <stroke
                android:width="0dp"
                android:color="#6f94c7" />

            <padding
                android:bottom="10dp"
                android:left="2dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:top="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="end"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_down" />  //your image
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

now in xml add: for the spinner

```
android:background="@drawable/custom_spinner"
```

Comment: After adding the background I am seeing the arrow, but the Material look is now replaced with an old Spinner look.

Comment: Thanks. The seconds option is better. The only thing is that the ripple effect on the click not working.

Comment: Do you know why the ImageView causing it not be shown at first place ?